# How to sort the data by a keyword of a csv file in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, csv, keyword

Is it possible to sort data of .csv file by a keyword in Python?

Suppose we write a .csv file and put some data in it. For example:

```
['www.google.com', 'www.kiet.edu','animals','www.yahoo.com' ,'birds','lion','www.youtube.com'])
```

Now I want to sort the data which have `.com` using Python. How could it be done?

Comment: take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['www.google.com', 'www.kiet.edu','animals','www.yahoo.com' ,'birds','lion','www.youtube.com']
nl = list([x for x in l if '.com' in x])
nl.sort()
print nl
```

Output `['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.youtube.com']`

First filter to element that contains *.com*, then sort.

Answer (score 0):

you simply read the file and store it in a variable named data. While reading the file line by line, simply check the lines containing .com and add them to list. \n is the line delimiter and we do not want to see it in our output. sorted(l) will sort the data in list.

```
data = open("file1.txt", "r")
l = []

i = 0
for val in data.readlines():
  if ".com" in val:
    l.append(str(val).replace("\n", ""))

print(sorted(l))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.